# Where should I save my subclasses? [Python, Best Practice]

Tags: python, oop, module, directory-structure

I'm looking to publish my current project and I wouldn't be happy with one that barely works.

Here's what I'm up to:
I have a package with a a BaseClass and a bunch of SubClass[1,2,3..]. Each is in its own module (is this ok?)

Here's my folder structure

```
package/
├── __init__.py
├── BaseClass.py
├── customclasses
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── SubClass1.py
│   ├── SubClass2.py
│   ├── ...
```

Each `SubClassX.py` looks like

```
...
class SubClassX(BaseClass):
...
```

`package/__init__.py` looks like this

```
from package.customclasses.SubClass1 import SubClass1
...
```

So I wouldn't have to import SubClassX.SubClassX every time (is *this* good?)

The problem is, I keep running into

```
TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments
```

Even when it seems it should work

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong or is it just an oversight?

Thanks in advance for any comments!

Forgot to mention, I'm using Python 3.9

Comment: I don't think you should have filenames exactly the same as class names. Leads to confusion.

Comment: You're right, and renaming the files reveals a circular import. Whoops